How to close most recently opened chrome window with python
i'm working on a python project in which I open a new chrome window, open a bunch of tabs in that window, and close that window. the problem is that I don't want to kill the chrome.exe process since I have other chrome windows open that I don't want closed. I've figured out opening a new window and the tabs already, but not only closing the new window yet.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

With something like vbscript, you can start a process, and get the process id of the process you just started. Look for something like this in Python, then you can just taskkill that process based on process id. See also: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html
